# Как реагировать на событие нажатия клавиши в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, события

Я только начинаю пользоваться Unity и не могу понять как реагировать на событие нажатие клавиши с помощью привязки функции к событию или даже в `Update()` с помощью `if`.

Как можно это сделать?

Comment: [Вот здесь](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/252898/226545) на Code Review я писал решение для виртуальной клавиатуры, как по мне - хороший пример.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    void Update()
    {
        //конкретная кнопка
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            Debug.Log("Key A");
        }

        //Любая кнопка
        if (Input.anyKeyDown)
        {
            Debug.Log("AnyKey");
        }

        //Ось (можно гибко настраивать Edit > Project Settings > Input Manager )
        if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") != 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("Horizontal move key");
        }
    }
```